# PHP Download JSON and CSV file from local directory

Tags: php

I aim to download the news.json file in a PHP website from my computer file directory. When click on a button, it calls the downloadFile.php to force download the file from my computer. The codes work for downloading other files like images and docs except json and csv files. Is there any way to download the mentioned file types or my code has some problem.

```
$file = ("C:\Users\THINKPAD\Downloads\my_file_name.png");
$filetype=filetype($file);
$filename=basename($file);

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($file);
```

Comment: I think I found the problem, I could not have the file name with "new" or "news", but if I use another name, it allows me to download. Anyone knows why it works this way???

Comment: No, we don't. We don't even know what the actual problem is yet, because you failed to describe it. "Not working" is _not_ a useful problem description.